# how to create economies of scale for a city?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

would anyone possibly explain through a vivid example how the size of a city could ***create*** such an ***economies of scale***?

In addition, I am learning English. Would you tell me your priceless explanations in more simple ways?

The size of a city creates economies of scale for things such as energy generation, recycling, and public transport.

Answer (score 1):

The items referenced in your example have high initial costs and low costs per user.  It costs a lot of money to set up a bus company, buy buses, build bus stops, etc.  But once you have done so, many people can take advantage of the public transit system.

Comment: Also, price per widget or unit of service typically drops when many widgets/units are purchased. Purchasing power increases.  Buy 1 computer from Acme Computing you might pay $1000 for it.  Buy 10,000 computers from Acme Computing and you'll get a (significantly) better deal.

Comment: So, is this correct? the bigger city would be, the more it takes advantage throw economiec of scale

Comment: Yes, assuming the resources are subject to economies of scale.